# How can I obtain a propery value inside an inherited Method in a Generic Class?

Tags: java, generics, multiple-inheritance

I'm writting a code like below, and I need to obtain a value of a child class from a static method of the parent class.

Can someone help me to solve it? Thank's in advanced.

```
public abstract class DataObject<T>{
    public static int GetAllTotal(){
        // How can I obtain a T propery called "code" = "001". 
        int cont = SQL.getTotalFromQuery(
                           "SELECT * from tblProducts where code = '001'"
        );
       return ffff
    }

    ...
}

public class Product extends DataObject<Product>{
    private String code = "001";
    public Product(){
    }
}

...

Product.GetAllTotal();
```

Comment: This probably shouldn't be static, as that won't work out very well with inheritance.

Comment: BTW, Java method names should not be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the following:

```
super.GetAllTotal();
```

In the child (derived) class.

Where `super` is the reference of the parent of a derived class in java.

Comment: Is there any way to do it without create a method in child class?

Comment: Yes you can call from the `constructor` of the child class and assign it to a class field to use it later on.

Comment: Is there any way to obtain an instance of T inside GetAllTotal method? Maybe Reflection?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you will need an object of the class to be able to access members dynamically from a static method.

Then you could define a public `getCode()` function in the parent that you override in the child class that returns the value of the `code` member variable.

Comment: What about reflection in GetAllTotal method? Can I know that Product.GetAllTotal() comes from Product class? If it is possible, can I create an instance of Product?

Comment: @user1410626 - It is possible, but it is slow, ugly and error-prone.  And you should restrict the visibility of `GetAllTotal()` to `protected` if you can.  As for creating the instance yourself, you might not get the code value you need.  How about going with the suggestion in my answer and adding a `DataObject` parameter to `GetAllTotal()`?  You will have to deal with warnings about unchecked calls, but it sounds like the lesser evil

Comment: @user1410626 - also, must `GetAllTotal()` be static?

Comment: Yes... I "need" that GetAllTotal be static. I want that all classes that are an inheritance of DataObject have some standard method. For example, Product have a property that contains the DDBB table name. That's the parameter I need in GetAllTotal. Will would it work if that property is static?

Comment: If you made the function non-static, and defined a `getCode()` (and whatever else you need) in `DataObject`, then overrode that function in the child class, you get the behavior you want without the problems you face trying to use a static function.  Static mmebers are tied to the class and do not work well with inheritance

Answer (score 0):

use the keyword `super` to access the reference of the parent class. In your case,

```
super.GetAllTotal();
```

Answer (score 0):

cant we make the GetAllTotal method parameterized to accept an argument, or their is some restriction in changing method definition

```
GetAllTotal(String code)
```